# Received header from Mail in JS

Tags: javascript, email, thunderbird

I am currently working on an extension for thunderbird, which needs the "Received" header from all unread mails. I hoped I could get the received header through the same method as the subject like in the tutorial from Mozilla but it wont work. 
Since it is my first time writing javascript code I would be very thankfull for every helping answer.

```
function listenup(){
console.log("Listening");
var newMailListener = {
    msgAdded: function(aMsgHdr) {
        if( !aMsgHdr.isRead ) { 
            console.log("Got Mail");
            var mimeConvert = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger/mimeconverter;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIMimeConverter);
            var subject =  mimeConvert.decodeMimeHeader(aMsgHdr.subject, null, false, true);
            var received =  mimeConvert.decodeMimeHeader(aMsgHdr.received, null, false, true);

            console.log(subject);
            console.log(received);

            if (false) {
                aMsgHdr.markFlagged(true);
            }
        }
    }
};

function init() {
    var notificationService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger/msgnotificationservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgFolderNotificationService);
    notificationService.addListener(newMailListener, notificationService.msgAdded);
}
addEventListener("load", init, true);
```

}

Comment: Can you include the details of you error?

Comment: the console from Thunderbird just tells me "Starting" (which is the start of my own functions) and "Listening" (which you see at the code snipped) and the tutorial which I used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_extensions/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Extension_Techniques/Filter_Incoming_Mail